# Dual monitors - graphical menu when switching

Tags: multitasking-view

When switching between projection modes using the keyboard shortcut (super + p), the modes just switch like crazy without any graphical interface like in widnows or any other distro (I don't know if I describe it clearly enough, that's why I'm attaching the screen from windows). This is quite annoying, just pressing the keys while the display is flashing until I get to the projection I need. It amazes me that I seem to be the only one who is bothered by this.
Is there a utility that solves this?

I would also appreciate having the plank and top bar on the extended monitor as well. I managed to achieve this once when I was playing around with modes, but it seems that it was more of a "bug".

[image: windows gui project dual monitor]